Oracle SQL - Query showing different dates depending which timezone being queried from
I'm trying to get the same dates to show up. Depending on the time zone the query is being run from, the results will show one day behind from what's shown on the actual table.
For the example below, how would I go about to get the queried dates to all show up as 6/3/2024 irrespective of the time zone the query is being run from?
Thanks in advance.
Example table,



CUST_CODE
ORD_NUM
SHIP_DATE




10001
0001
03-JUN-2024



Query result using sql below from different time zones,
SELECT CUST_CODE, ORD_NUM, SHIP_DATE
FROM   ORDERS




CUST_CODE
ORD_NUM
SHIP_DATE  (EST)




10001
0001
6/3/2024 12:00:00 AM






CUST_CODE
ORD_NUM
SHIP_DATE  (MDT)




10001
0001
6/2/2024 10:00:00 PM






CUST_CODE
ORD_NUM
SHIP_DATE  (PDT)




10001
0001
6/2/2024 09:00:00 PM




What data type is the column - timestamp with local time zone? Or are you converting it from another data type, explicitly or implicitly? (It doesn't appear so from your example query, but maybe you're running that within an application and e.g. a JDBC get is converting it.) And what time zone is the data in the table supposed to represent?

@Alex Poole, the data type for column SHIP_DATE is date.  The data in the table is supposed to represent EST. Thank you.

Date is not time zone-aware, so you must be doing something to convert it to another data type that is. Where is that query being run from - pretty sure it's not a basic SQL client as that won't change data type unless you tell it to, so is it your own application, and if so how is that retrieving the query result and manipulating it afterwards?

@Alex Poole. you're right. When I run the query using Oracle SQL Developer, it just gives me a ship date without a time. The query is being setup in another program called Workspace, and then the sql is loaded in as a KPI on an HTML5 platform.  I can definitely see that the Workspace application is converting the data type and adding a time at the end of date.

@Alex Poole, I've tried using TO_CHAR(CAST(D.ORD_TO_SHIP_DATE AS TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'US/EASTERN', 'MM-DD-YYYY') ORD_TO_SHIP_DATE, and although it gives me a date in Workspace without a time, when it's loaded into the HTML5 platform, the SHIP_DATE column is blank. I may have to engage the developers to see what they say.

Given what you have said, the problem is probably not with Oracle (as the column is a DATE which is not time-zone aware) - it is either with the "Workspace" program or, maybe, on the client-side (if you are using JavaScript or something similar to dynamically load the data).

@mrdiu - a date still has a time, which SQL Developer will show you if you use to_char() or change your NLS settings. It's unclear if your values have non-midnight times, but as the EST result is midnight I'd guess not. Anyway, if the problem is in Workspace or your HTML5 platform, then casting to timestamp on the database side before converting to a string isn't going to help, and it sounds like the application expects a datetime not a string. So yes, involving the developers is probably a good plan *8-)

@Alex Poole, I just heard back from support, and apparently they asked the developer the question and the response was, 'you will need to update the queries taking into account timezone. You may need to add logic to to calculate offset if required.'  Not the answer I was hoping for, but does any of that make sense to you? Thanks.

@mrdiu - not entirely... it depends which timezone they mean, and how they execute the query and retrieve and then manipulate the results. And they haven't given you any of that information.


you will need to update the queries taking into account timezone. You may need to add logic to to calculate offset if required

It still isn't clear which timezone they mean (end-user, application server, database...) or how they are executing the query and retrieving and manipulating the date value.
But based on what little they have said, the only way I can immediately see they'd get the effect you're seeing is if they are retrieving the date as a timestamp with a time zone - which may be implied - and converting it to the local time. And it's assuming or defaulting the time zone somewhere along the way.
So... you could retrieve the date as a timestamp with time zone to avoid some of the possible ambiguity, but it still depends how they manipulate it.
You can specify which time zone it actually represents, as a timestamp with time zone:
FROM_TZ(CAST(SHIP_DATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') AS SHIP_DATE

Or you can do that but convert it to the session time zone:
FROM_TZ(CAST(SHIP_DATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') AT TIME ZONE SESSIONTIMEZONE AS SHIP_DATE

Or you can do that but turn it back into a plain timestamp, which seems an unnecessary step but who knows what they're expecting:
CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(SHIP_DATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') AT TIME ZONE SESSIONTIMEZONE AS TIMESTAMP) AS SHIP_DATE

Or, perhaps most likely based on the comment, pretend that the date is in their time zone to begin with, as a timestamp with time zone but using whatever the current session time zone is:
FROM_TZ(CAST(SHIP_DATE AS TIMESTAMP), SESSIONTIMEZONE) AS SHIP_DATE

which is the same as:
CAST(SHIP_DATE AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) AS SHIP_DATE

but more explicitly shows that the session time zone is being used.  Either way, though, this potentially has a problem with DST. If your ship_date value is always midnight then you're probably OK, but if it has non-midnight times then it's possible one of those won't be valid for the session time zone. Again, you're probably OK if the sessions are always at least in the USA, but still... something to bear in mind.
You can see how those affect the actual value returned for different session time zones in this fiddle. What you can't see is how those various return values would have handled by your application, of course.
Without further assistance from support/development (or documentation) you may have to try these and see which, if any, resolves the problem. It's entirely possible they're doing something else and none of these will help...

thank you for this!  Sorry for delay in response, I've been so busy.  I did have a chance to test out every query, and although the query results look good in the 'Workspace' application, when it is loaded into HTML5 platform, the time conversion is still happening.  Query run from MDT location shows one day behind 6/2/2024 with time of 10:00:00 PM.

OK, well without knowing what the HTML5 platform (whatever that is) is actually doing, I'm not sure what you can do to counter it. It kind of sounds like the front end is adjusting the data in the application to the end-user's browser's time zone, so unless you know that TZ and can pass it through to the query to adjust it, it seems to be out of your control? (And even if you can - yuck?) Or you somehow indicate that this value shouldn't be adjusted, but doesn't sound like they support that. Sorry, I think you need to go back to the developers again. Good luck...

,I informed the developer of the tests I have run so far and have not heard back yet.  The user code in HTML5 platform where query is being run from, I could probably set the users time zone to EST, but not sure if it would have any implications. I'll give that a shot.

you can convert the SHIP_DATE to a fixed time zone (such as UTC) and then extract the date:
SELECT CUST_CODE, 
       ORD_NUM, 
       -- Convert SHIP_DATE to UTC and then extract the date part
       TRUNC(SHIP_DATE AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS SHIP_DATE
FROM   ORDERS;

if you want date to reflect a specific local time zone (like America/New_York), you can adjust the query in this way:
SELECT CUST_CODE, 
       ORD_NUM, 
       -- Convert SHIP_DATE to a specific time zone (eg. 'America/New_York') and then extract the date part
       TRUNC(SHIP_DATE AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') AS SHIP_DATE
FROM   ORDERS;


The starting data type maters. If SHIP_DATE is a date then this will error, unless you cast it to timestamp. If it's a plain timestamp (or date cast to timestamp) or timestamp with local time zone then it will pick up the session time zone when it's implicitly converted to timestamp with time zone to allow at time zone to be applied. If it's already timestamp with time zone then converting to another time zone before truncating is probably wrong too.

You need to Convert the Date to your desired time Zone , use this code to do that as a reference :
select cast(date'2014-04-08' as timestamp) d1, cast(date'2014-04-08' as timestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern' d2 from dual

Results will be as the Following :


Again, you're relying on implicit conversion to the session time zone before converting to US/Eastern; and as it's an application layer higher up that's causing the issue - not the data itself - it's unclear this would make any difference anyway.

lets be clear you are saying that you are requesting a date but the date change depending on the client session location ? if so then why not just change it from client side ?

Yes, that does seem to be what the question is asking, and OP's comments confirm. The OP doesn't seem to know quite where in the stack the conversion and adjustment are happening - but the query doesn't seem to be the problem.
